# how to use all columns (*) in select statement from different tables using UNION ALL?

Tags: sql-server

I have 10 tables of which 4 tables have 99 columns and 6 tables have 100 columns. I have to combine using UNION ALL. when executing SQL query getting below error

> Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

I understood the reason of error is for not same number of columns. I tried using NULL as Column100 but still getting same error.

please can anyone suggest me how to use * and UNION ALL in SQL query.

Thanks.

Comment: you can name all of the columns in the same order in all the tables, where you have a missing column, just do NULL AS MissingColumnName in the SELECT.  You can auto generate SELECT SQL in SSMS by right clicking on the table and selecting the option to generate SELECT SQL - that isn't exactly the answer you wanted, because you said you wanted to do SELECT * - but I don't see why you need to use SELECT *

Comment: I would question a system that has tables with 99 columns, it may be appropriate in your situation, but I've rarely seen such a thing!

Comment: try to union all with two table, if success add one more tble and so on, find which table throw error then compare that table with others

Answer (score 2):

If the extra column *happens* to be at the beginning or end *and* the other columns are in exactly the same order, then you can add the column manually:

```
select t99.*, 't99' as col
from t99
union all
select t100.*
from t100;
```

But really, is it that hard to list the columns?  An explicit column list is much less prone to error.  And, it will work regardless of where the 100th column appears.

You can get the list in SQL Server Management Studio by clicking on the table name.  You can also run a query such as:

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 't99';
```

And then use the column names to construct the query (I often use a spreadsheet for this purpose).

Comment: right click on table name in SSMS and then 'SCRIPT TABLE' then 'SELECT' etc

Comment: Thanks. I have tried listing columns one by one. but still getting same error. that's where I am confusing why the error still appearing?

Comment: The error happens because DB do not know what to put in the missing column. You want single result set, but do not provide all information's for one part of UNION ALL.

Answer (score 0):

UNION requres that columns before and after it  MATCH.
You can not do union of 99 columns and then 100 columns. You have to either provide dummy value for 100th column that do not exist in that table, or tell DB to skipp that column.

So add to the smaller table select:
`NULL AS missing-column-name`

Or list all the common columns by hand omitting columns that do not exists in both.